# Python spynner and gtk3 issue

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, gtk3, spynner

I am always getting the following error on executing the script. I am trying to attach spynner window in a Gtk window. Is spynner will only works with gtk2??

```
import sys
import spynner
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk
from gi.repository import GObject, GLib

class App:
  def __init__(self):
    self.browser = spynner.Browser()
    self.create_interior()
    self.window.show_all()

  def create_interior(self):    
    self.window = Gtk.Window()
    self.window.set_border_width(0)
    self.mainvbox = Gtk.VBox(False, 0)
    self.mainvbox.pack_start(self.browser,False, False, 2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    Gtk.main()
```

Gtk-ERROR **: GTK+ 2.x symbols detected. Using GTK+ 2.x and GTK+ 3 in the same process is not supported
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)

Comment: Spynner browser is not a GTK widget (or an embeddable widget for any toolkit) as far as I know... Are you sure this should work?

Comment: @jku I was trying to make this work. Embedding spynner inside a Gtk+3 Window. But always getting that error. If I changed Gtk3 to gtk2, then this works without any problem.