# How to auto fill input field with pygtk+ WebKit

Tags: javascript, python, webkit, gtk, pygtk

I was trying to automate google search with pygtk+ WebKit. How do I can insert some search queries in input field and then submit? Executing the javascript is not working.

```
from gi.repository import WebKit
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk

def get_source(webobj, frame):
    web.execute_script("document.getElementById('gbqfq').value='test';")

win = Gtk.Window()

web = WebKit.WebView()
web.open("http://google.com")
web.connect("load-finished", get_source)
win.add(web)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: Can you please define "not working".

Comment: @jku getting error : **`TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById('gbqfq').value='test'')`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last I got it working with some minor changes. Thanks for @user871199 and @Syed

```
from gi.repository import WebKit
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk

def get_source(webobj, frame):
  doc = web.get_dom_document()
  element = doc.get_elements_by_name("q")
  child = element.item(0)
  child.set_value("test")
  SubBtn = doc.get_elements_by_name("btnG")
  btn = SubBtn.item(0)
  btn.click()

win = Gtk.Window()

web = WebKit.WebView()
web.open("http://google.com")
web.connect("load-finished", get_source)
win.add(web)
win.connect('destroy', lambda w: Gtk.main_quit())
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Why can't try like this?

```
from gi.repository import WebKit
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk

def get_source(webobj, frame):
    web.execute_script("document.getElementById('gbqfq').value='test';")
    web.execute_script("document.getElementById('gbqf').submit();")

win = Gtk.Window()

web = WebKit.WebView()
web.open("http://google.com/")
web.connect("load-finished", get_source)
win.add(web)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Why are you try to do like this? Is it worth for search queries using `WebKit`?

Comment: No bro, I need something like spynner and PyQt4.QtWebKit can do. In spynner I can fill the input field by **browser.fill("input[name=q]", "test")**. But the main problem is spynner is not compatible with Gtk+ [link]( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24079615/python-spynner-and-gtk3-issue)

Comment: same error :
**
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById('gbqfq').value='test'')

TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById('gbqf').submit') **

Comment: same code above. No changes. I tried it with gtk also. same problem there. Javascript is working(confirmed with alert). But the problem is javascript cant find the DOM element even after load-finished.

Comment: Which os and which distro are you using?

Answer (score 0):

See following.

To find methods supported by python and objects available, please check file /usr/share/gir-1.0/WebKit-3.0.gir on Ubuntu platforms. I don't remember how I got that file, but I think it gets installed if you install dev version of library. This will give you all the API's supported by Webkit/python as you are using GIR and its corresponding names.

```
from gi.repository import WebKit
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk

def get_source(webobj, frame):
  doc = web.get_dom_document()
  element = doc.get_element_by_id("gbqfq")
  element.set_value("test");


win = Gtk.Window()

web = WebKit.WebView()
web.open("http://google.com")
web.connect("load-finished", get_source)
win.add(web)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: Your answer was almost correct. Special thanks for **/usr/share/gir-1.0/WebKit-3.0.gir**.